# The Zend Engine API version 320170718 which is installed, is newer

Tags: symfony, xdebug, php-internals

I am currently experiencing a problem with xdebug. I wanted to do a

> php bin/console cache:clear

for my Symfony application but it got me this error:

> Warning: Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0

So I installed the latest version of Xdebug and put "zend_extension" in the php.ini

I restart my order and the, a new error:

> Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 320160303. The Zend Engine API
>   version 320170718 which is installed, is newer.

I tell you that, I do not know what to do, can you help me? If you need more information, do not hesitate.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: First error tells that the Xdebug extension was attempted to be loaded as a normal extension (e.g. `extensio=xdebug...`). If you need Xdebug, just find the place where it is getting loaded and fix the line (use `zend_extension=xdebug...`) . Now, your 2nd error tells that the Xdebug you have installed is for older PHP. `320170718` is for PHP 7.2 while `320160303` is for PHP 7.1

Comment: My version of PHP is so high for the latest version of xdebug coup .. Thank you for your answer!